# How to set AnyChart Candlestick colors dynamic?

Tags: javascript, web, candlestick-chart, anychart

I want to set Candlestick Colors dynamically. But i don't know how.

So i passed the Parameter true as said on anychart Doc to anychart.stock
constructor und defined a field caled color on Dataset with mapped field
as example showed below.

Anyone get a Solutions ?

Ref to Dok: https://docs.anychart.com/Stock_Charts/Data#individual_point_settings

```
anychart.onDocumentReady(function() {

    // create a data table
    var table = anychart.data.table('x');
    // add data
    table.addData([{
        'x': '2015-12-24',
        'open': 511.53,
        'high': 514.98,
        'low': 505.79,
        'close': 506.40,
        'fill': '#00FF00'
    }]);

    // create a stock chart
    var chart = anychart.stock(true);

    // create a mapping
    var mapping = table.mapAs({
        'open': 'open',
        'high': 'high',
        'low': 'low',
        'close': 'close',
        'fill': 'fill'
    });

    // add a series using the mapping
    chart.plot(0).candlestick(mapping).name('ACME Corp.');

    // set container id for the chart
    chart.container('container');

    // initiate chart drawing
    chart.draw();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your approach was absolutely right! The only problem was that candlestick series has no 'fill' setting, it has risingFill and fallingFill. So, all you need is to map it using these settings. You can check the working sample based on your code in the comment below. Also, you can learn more about candlestick settings in [this article](https://docs.anychart.com/Stock_Charts/Series/Japanese_Candlestick#appearance).

Comment: Thx you very much. Your Solution works perfektly! With the mapped Falling Fill, Rising Fill all work as expected for me.

Comment: Add on question: is there a way to override the color of a single candle? Suppose green up candles, but for a certain event you would like to make a single candle dark-green

Comment: @hootnot Yes, it's possible! To achieve that you should override this point data in the table. For example, you need to update color fill for the point with date 2021-01-01: `dataTable.addData([ {x: 2021-01-01, value: 12, fill: 'dark-green'} ])`

Comment: @AnyChartSupport : as you suggested  I've added the risingFill and fallingFill to the code in the question. The 'fallingFill' gives indeed a red candle, but the 'risingFill' gives an orange candle instead of a green one. Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Comment: @hootnot please, contact support@anychart.com and provide your chart code snippet. We will review it and give a solution based on your code.

Answer (score 0):

according to the answer by anychart the code becomes like in the codeblock. With an additional candle added I would expect to see a green and a red candle. But only the red candle is correctly displayed according 'fallingFill'. The 'risingFill' does not show a green candle.

```
anychart.onDocumentReady(function() {

// create a data table
var table = anychart.data.table('x');
// add data
table.addData([{
    'x': '2015-12-24',
    'open': 511.53,
    'high': 514.98,
    'low': 505.79,
    'close': 506.40,
    'fallingFill': '#FF0000',
},
 {
    'x': '2015-12-25',
    'open': 521.53,
    'high': 524.98,
    'low': 515.79,
    'close': 524,    // 516.40, 
    'risingFill': '#00FF00'
}]);

// create a stock chart
var chart = anychart.stock(true);

// create a mapping
var mapping = table.mapAs({
    'open': 'open',
    'high': 'high',
    'low': 'low',
    'close': 'close',
    'risingFill': 'risingFill', 
    'fallingFill': 'fallingFill'
});

// add a series using the mapping
chart.plot(0).candlestick(mapping).name('ACME Corp.');

// set container id for the chart
chart.container('container');

// initiate chart drawing
chart.draw();
});
```

Comment: making the second candle close > open makes the risingFill work ok. Overriding both will always force the color to be set. (@anychart-support:  thanks for the feedbeack)